# How to load a Teachable Machine Audio Model from Project Files

Tags: javascript, teachable-machine

I'm having trouble utilizing the Teachable Machine's audio model code snippet to create an offline model. I downloaded the metadata and model json's and would like to accomplish something similar to

```
async function createModel() {
       const checkpointURL = 'model.json'; // model topology
       const metadataURL = 'metadata.json'; // model metadata
       const recognizer = await speechCommands.create('model.json', 'metadata.json');
       return recognizer;
   }
```

where you'd usually put both links to the files as arguments to the create() method. I saw a post extremely similar to my issue, but it was for the pose teachable machine model and I can't seem to find a similar load() function in the audio model's speech-commands' script that would allow me to get these files from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Just prepend `file://` to the json's directories.